# Android: remove divider of some listitems in listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, baseadapter, divider

I've created a listview with a `BaseAdapter`. I want some of the listitems to have a divider, but from some of the listitems, I want to remove the divider. I know you can remove the divider of the whole list by setting `.setDivider(null)` and `.setDividerHeight(0)`, but is it also possible to remove the divider from a single listitem inside a list?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could disable the divider for the whole list and set a custom View for each `ListItem`, e.g. setting different background drawables with or without a bottom border.

Comment: Seems like a lot of overhead, but I'm afraid that's the only way to go :(

Comment: How to deal with clickable items? If separator is part of list item then on click selected area will contain separator too that looks ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can remove divider from specific list items using the `getView` method in your adapter (which extends the baseadapter)

ofc you have something like `data` in your adapter which refers to the data been displayed into the listview, so in your `getview` method check for the specific items like this:

```
if(data[position].ID == YourElemetnsID)
inflate with the specific list item layout
else
inflate with the general list item layout
```